# Authenticate Custom Training Job in Vertex AI with Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run a Custom Training Job to deploy my model in Vertex AI directly from a Jupyterlab. This Jupyterlab is instantiated from a Vertex AI Managed Notebook where I already specified the service account.

My aim is to deploy the training script that I specify to the method `CustomTrainingJob` directly from the cells of my notebook. This would be equivalent to pushing an image that contains my script to **container registry** and deploying the Training Job manually from the UI of Vertex AI (in this way, by specifying the service account, I was able to corectly deploy the training job). However, I need everything to be executed from the same notebook.

In order to specify the credentials to the `CustomTrainingJob` of aiplatform, I execute the following cell, where all variables are correctly set:

```python
import google.auth
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials

source_credentials = google.auth.default()
target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
source_credentials=source_credentials,
target_principal='SERVICE_ACCOUNT.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION, staging_bucket=BUCKET_NAME)

job = aiplatform.CustomTrainingJob(
    display_name=JOB_NAME,
    script_path=SCRIPT_PATH,
    container_uri=MODEL_TRAINING_IMAGE,
    credentials=target_credentials
)
```

When after the `job.run()` command is executed it seems that the credentials are not correctly set. In particular, the following error is returned:

```python
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/impersonated_credentials.py in _update_token(self, request)
    254 
    255         # Refresh our source credentials if it is not valid.
--> 256         if not self._source_credentials.valid:
    257             self._source_credentials.refresh(request)
    258 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'valid'
```

I also tried different ways to configure the credentials of my service account but none of them seem to work. In this case it looks like the tuple that contains the source credentials is missing the 'valid' attribute, even if the method `google.auth.default()` only returns two values.

Comment: Did you `gcloud config set project  XXXXX` inside the notebook ?

Answer (score 1):

To run the custom training job using a service account, you could try using the [`service_account` argument for job.run()](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.CustomTrainingJob#google_cloud_aiplatform_CustomTrainingJob_run), instead of trying to set credentials. As long as the notebook executes as a user that has act-as permissions for the chosen service account, this should let you run the custom training job as that service account.

Answer (score 0):

Using service account credentials from details stored as a Json file.

1. create a **credential.json** [from your service account](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account) (add file to .gitignore)
2. load Service Account file as an object with

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials.json)
```

3. initialize aiplatform instance

```
aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location, credentials=credentials)
```

Note that this question doesn't mention neither Kubeflow nor Pipeline, if Kubeflow sdk is needed, the authentication with aiplatform is not valid or enough for kfp.